# What is the solution when y approaches x?

Tags: limits

I found this limit in our technical diploma mathematics eBook.

And there's no explanation in the book about this kind of equations.

And I don't know the solution of this kind of equations.

[image]

Comment: But why the negative votes for my question? What is wrong with my post?

Comment: Are aware about the definition of continuity? Show also your work in order to do not receive downvotes.

Comment: You should not formulate the OP in the form "What is the solution for this?" but showing your efforts and doubts. In this way comunity can try to help you better.

Comment: @PerchEagle When you signed up there was a section on how to ask questions in this site. It looks like you skipped it...

Comment: What is my work? I studied this eBook and there's basics of limits, continuity, limit from left and right, which are all fine, but this one does not have a real number of x. What should I do? Do I have just to substitute x in y, which the result is the same equation, that what's not clear to me, I don't know this kind of equations. There's no work or explanation about this limit in the book, that's why I posted a question, not to expect downvotes actually, I'm serious I don't know if y approaches to x!

Comment: @PerchEagle without any other explanation, $x$ stands for any real value; then observe that $f$ is continuos in $\mathbb{R}$, can you see why?

Comment: OK, so x could be any value. That's what I thought at the beginning, that x is just a free scale along the x-axis. So just I have to pick any value and substitute that in the equation, correct?

Comment: @DonAntonio Well, I skipped this section but I thought the question is simple and doesn't need me to show any other related points to the question because I thought I can post the question as simple as I thought.

Comment: @gimusi OK, I thought it's just a simple question for anyone who is expert is mathematics, would know the answer right away. And you're right I may change the title.

Comment: @PerchEagle yes it is only a symbol for the value assumed by $f(y)$ for $y=x$.

Comment: OK, thank you, sorry my thoughts went away of this simple idea that's just x is any value, I just wasn't sure and I couldn't tell the students about it right away, I thought I have to be sure of this and ask about it here. Thanks again,

Comment: @PerchEagle You are welcome! I think that for the following OP you will formulate better! Bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Remember that for $f$ continuos

$$\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=f(x_0)$$